# Find api message ID from GMail web interface

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

When looking at a GMail message, the URL used to simply contain the message ID that I could then easily query with the GMail API.

E.g. when looking at an email, the URL was something like

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox/167d7bc198aa3059
```

This was convenient for development and debugging problems with specific emails. I could just make a call to get_user_message with 167d7bc198aa3059

But now, the same URL is expressed like this:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox/WhctKJVJZkbrQVvLJqnhlZMQRckHrPbrhZMXXWzVswzckGCcRjQSZzjsPwcfhsDNXsFTDTG
```

How can I find back the message Id to query on my API from the new GMail URL format?

Or is there a simple encoding/decoding that transforms

```
WhctKJVJZkbrQVvLJqnhlZMQRckHrPbrhZMXXWzVswzckGCcRjQSZzjsPwcfhsDNXsFTDTG
```

into

```
167d7bc198aa3059
```

?

Comment: crap, I need the same thing.  I need customers to be able to easily give me an id so we can debug....gah!!!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following code in the console to obtain the message ID:

```
document.querySelector('[data-message-id]').getAttribute('data-legacy-message-id')
```

Or just inspect the DOM:

[image: Inspect DOM]

Comment: I won't have access to the HTML, just the URL

Comment: Ah. I'm sorry I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

In the new Gmail

```
thread-id
document.querySelector('[data-legacy-thread-id]').getAttribute('data-legacy-thread-id')
message-id (when you enter an email)
document.querySelector('[data-message-id]').getAttribute('data-legacy-message-id')
```

You can get all emails list with [google API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list?apix=true#try-it)

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: I won't have access to the HTML, just the URL