# How can I retrieve the messageID of an e-mail that is currently open Gmail? I'd like to label the email through Gmail API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

I would like to label an email that is currently open using

```
POST https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/{id}/modify
```

The problem is that I cannot find the `{id}` of the current message anywhere. When using `users.messages.list` I still don't know which `messageID` to use from that list.

Does anyone know where to find the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54583554/8112540

This returns the message ID of a Gmail email that is currently open: `document.querySelector('[data-message-id]').getAttribute('data-legacy-message-id')`